# About the first positive root of $\sum_{k=1}^n\tan(kx)=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, approximation

I am looking for the first positive solution $x_n$ of the equation $$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\tan(kx)=0 \qquad \qquad (n\geq 2)$$ It is simple to show that $$\frac \pi{2n}<x_n <\frac \pi{2(n-1)}$$ The numerical solution is very easy (and inexpensive in terms of computer resources) to obtain using Newton, Halley or Householder methods but the analytical solution does not seem to be possible as soon as $n\geq 7$ (up to $n=6$, using $x=\tan^{-1}(t)$, the equation factors as products of polynomials of low degree). For example solving $f_6$ reduces to the problem of finding the first positive root of $$t \left(t^2-3\right) \left(t^6-21 t^4+35 t^2-7\right) \left(23 t^8-202 t^6+136
   t^4-22 t^2+1\right)=0$$ (which is feasible even if tedious) while for $f_7$, the root which is looked for is solution of $$44 t^{16}-763 t^{14}+4375 t^{12}-10067 t^{10}+9199 t^8-3593 t^6+589 t^4-41 t^2+1=0$$ (the other factors were not printed).

Looking at the numerical results for $2\leq n\leq 10000$, my surprise has been to notice that the solution is $$x_n\approx \frac \pi{2n-1}\tag 1$$ which the reciprocal of the harmonic mean of the bounds ( this is exactly true for $n=2$ ).

For $x_4$, the approximation gives $\approx 0.448799$ while the exact solution is $\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{9+\sqrt{17}}}{4}\right)\approx 0.437896$.

For $x_{10000}$, the approximation gives $0.000157087$ while the "exact" solution is $0.000157097$.

Using $y_n=\frac \pi{2n-1}$, polynomial regressions $$x_n=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i y^i$$ lead to extremely good fits with highly significant parameters. As an example, for $m=4$ 
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +0.997756 & 0.0000157 & \{+0.997726,+0.997786\} \\
 b & -0.125612 & 0.0001336 & \{-0.125874,-0.125350\} \\
 c & +0.202807 & 0.0002973 & \{+0.202224,+0.203390\} \\
 d & -0.077174 & 0.0001766 & \{-0.077520,-0.076828\} \\
\end{array}$$
Even with a single term in the regression, $R^2=0.999886$.

My attempts based on Taylor series around the approximation were totally unsuccessful.

> **My questions are :**
>
> 1.Is there any way to justify $(1)$ and/or to obtain a better approximation ?
>
> 2.Could an asymptotics of the solution be derived ?

**Edit**

After @Did's very interesting comment, I generated the solutions $x_n$ for $1000\leq n\leq 250000$ $(\Delta n =1000)$ and made a curve fit to the model $$x_n=\frac{\pi }{a n+b+\frac{c}{\log (n)}}$$ The fit is extremely good (all residuals being smaller than $2\times 10^{-12}$) and the parameters are highly significant
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +2.00000 & 5.8\times 10^{-9} & \{+2.00000,+2.00000\} \\
 b & -0.02216 & 0.000108935 & \{-0.02237,-0.02194\} \\
 c & -1.74434 & 0.000719344 & \{-1.74576,-1.74293\} \\
\end{array}$$

This is almost exactly what @Did suggested !!

**Update**

After Daniel Fischer's answer and Did's comment, I restarted the fitting work for the range $5\times 10^4\leq n\leq 5\times 10^5$ $(\Delta n =10^3)$  and used, as a model, $$x_n=\frac{\pi }{a n+\frac{b}{\log (n)}}$$ 
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +2.00000 & 6.02 \times 10^{-9}& \{+2.00000,+2.00000\} \\
 b & -1.95234 & 0.00545 & \{-1.96306,-1.94162\} \\
\end{array}$$ I also considered separately $y_n=\frac{2n_n}{2n x_n-\pi}$ for which
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 c & 1.02127 & 0.00008 & \{1.02112,1.02142\} \\
\end{array}$$ This confirms the previous fit. In order to double check, I also minimized the sum of the squares of relative errors : this lead to the same result $(a=2.00000,b=-1.96355)$.

I also consider (as Did asked after Daniel Fischer's answer) $$x_n\approx\frac{\pi}{2n}\left(1+\frac{c}{n\log n}\right)$$ for which was obtained $$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 c & 0.97571 & 0.00123 & \{0.97329,0.97813\} 
\end{array}$$

Now, considering the two models $$x_n^{(1)}=\frac{\pi }{2 \left(n-\frac{1}{\log (n)}\right)} \qquad x_n^{(2)}=\frac{\pi}{2n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)$$ over the set of data points the sum of squared errors are respectively $1.24\times 10^{-20}$ and $6.94\times 10^{-23}$.

A friend of mine challenged me asking to show the iterations of the root finding method for $n=10^6$. Here they are

$$x_0= 1.570796440492926 \times 10^{-6}$$
 $$x_1= 1.570796438443414 \times 10^{-6} $$
 $$x_2= 1.570796438479340 \times 10^{-6} $$
 $$x_3= 1.570796438479351 \times 10^{-6}$$

***Many thanks to all of you for your contributions.***

Comment: I performed some naive computation and it shows $\pi/x_n$ tends to $2n$  instead of $2n-1$. However, I know nothing about numerical methods so probably I am not getting the right results :(

Comment: @CaveJohnson. The problem is that this would correspond to the left asymptote. So, it cannot be the solution. If $n\to \infty$ , the $1$ does not matter (as you noticed). Thanks for playing with my junk ! Cheers.

Comment: are you certain that $x_3$ is exactly $\pi/5$ ?

Comment: @mercio. Thanks for pointing my mistake !

Comment: I'm a bit spooked because intuitively I would expect $\tan(x_n)$ to be a $\theta(n \log n)$ and not a $\theta(n)$

Comment: @mercio. Could you elaborate, please ? This could be very interesting, for sure. Thanks.

Comment: In which sense exactly do you mean $x_n \approx \frac{\pi}{2n - 1}$? because both terms converge to $0$ so $|x_n - \frac{\pi}{2n - 1}| \rightarrow 0$ won't be interesting

Comment: @themaker. For finite value of $n$, $x_n \approx \frac{\pi}{2n - 1}$ "looks" to be a quite reasonable approximation. I totally agree that the limit would be $0$ is $n\to \infty$. What I look for is a rigorous justification of the approximation or, essentially, a better one as well as the asymptotics.

Comment: approximating the sum by an integral (which should be justified for large $n$) yields a condition $\log\left(\frac{\cos(n x)}{\cos(x)}\right)\approx0$. Does this help?

Comment: @tired. I suppose that you are thinking about the Euler-MacLaurin formula. Is this your idea ?

Comment: something along this lines, but to be honest, i'm not sure if this is a promising direction

Comment: my approch seems quiet good for some of the roots but on the other hand it looses them partly..strange.. tomorrow i have access to mathematica then i will give this a more thorough try

Comment: @tired. Thanks for your time and ideas.

Comment: The first positive root $x_n$ happens just after $nx$ crosses the $a=\frac{\pi}2$ boundary since $\tan(u)\to-\infty$ when $u>a$, $u\to a$. Thus, $nx=a+y_n$ where $y_n\to0$ and the negative term $$\tan(nx)=-\cot(y_n)\sim-\frac1{y_n}$$ should compensate the sum of positive terms $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan(kx_n)\approx\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cot(ka/n)\approx\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}n/(ka)\approx n\log n/a$$ (This equivalent should be checked.) This seems to indicate that $$y_n\approx a/(n\log n)$$ and $$x_n=a/n+a/(n^2\log n)(1+o(1))$$ that is, $$x_n\approx\frac{\pi}{2\left(n-\frac1{\log n}\right)}$$

Comment: ...In the sense that $$\left(nx_n-\frac{\pi}2\right)n\log n\to\frac{\pi}2$$

Comment: @Did, i had the same idea but later so i  would defer a possiple answer based on this approach to you...

Comment: @tired No, no, please do not feel constrained by my comment, there is no real proof there, just ideas to be checked, so, go ahead!

Comment: @Did. This is very interesting and gives a track to work on. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, and even, who knows, the result... :-)

Comment: @Did. Your idea was just fantastic ! Have a look at my edit. Thanks again !

Comment: Mmmh, $b$ and $c$ are not what they "should" be. I might try to formalize the argument more carefully to see if/why the predictions $(b,c)=(0,-2)$ are incorrect. Well done for the simulations.

Comment: @Did. After your **Mmmh**, I fitted $n x_n$ (this is almost a constant) using as a model $\frac{\pi  n}{a n+b+\frac{c}{\log (n)}}$. What I got is $$n x_n=\frac{\pi  n}{2.00000n-0.01822-\frac{1.77115}{\log (n)}}$$ which is almost identical to the previous one. And, what about $\frac{2}{\log (\pi )}\approx 1.74714$ ?

Comment: might it be that in the limit of large $N$, $\tan(\frac{\pi N}{2}x)$ is already balanced by $\tan(\frac{\pi (N-1)}{2 }x)$? this would mean that we get corrections $\sim C/N^2$ instead of the $C \log(N)/N^2$

Comment: @tired. How could we check that ? Numerically, I already was in trouble with $n=250000$. In any manner, be sure I appreciate your cooperation. This is really the beauty of this site : meet people, share ideas, help other and so on. Cheers and thanks again (but let us continue on this !!)

Comment: @Did Your predictions are correct. But for smaller $n$, there's enough lower-order noise to disturb the empirical fit.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What happens when you fit $$x_n\approx\frac{\pi}{2n}\left(1+\frac{c}{n\log n}\right)$$ for the value of $c$, using your data, say, on the range of $n$ between $100'000$ and $250'000$?

Comment: @Did. I have to go now. I shall do it tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Did. Done and impressive ! Have a look to my update. Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent. So, we are not far from $c=1$...

Comment: @Did. Not far at all, for sure. $b=1$, $c=1$ "seem' to be the solution. I want to deeply thank you for your contibution, help, comments ... This has been a great story. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

[Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) is [spot on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961871/about-the-first-positive-root-of-sum-k-1n-tankx-0#comment4027333_1961871). I'm not surprised, because he usually is, but I had to calculate to be sure that the used approximations were good enough to yield the right result.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, let

$$f_n(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \tan (kx)$$

and $x_n$ the smallest positive zero of $f_n$. Then $f_n$ is an entire $\pi$-periodic meromorphic function with simple poles at the points of

$$P = \biggl\{ \frac{2m+1}{2k}\pi : m \in \mathbb{Z},\, 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\biggr\}.$$

On $\mathbb{R}\setminus P$, $f_n$ is real valued, and $f_n' > 0$, so $f_n$ maps each interval between consecutive poles diffeomorphically onto $\mathbb{R}$. The case $n = 1$ is trivial ($f_1 = \tan$), and for $n \geqslant 2$ the two smallest positive poles are at $\frac{\pi}{2n}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2(n-1)}$. Since $f_n(0) = 0$ and $f_n' > 0$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus P$, we have $f_n(x) > 0$ for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2n}$, so it follows that $x_n \in \bigl(\frac{\pi}{2n},\frac{\pi}{2(n-1)}\bigr)$, and $f_n$ has - for $n \geqslant 2$ - no other zeros in that interval. It is easily seen that $x_2 = \frac{\pi}{3}$, so in the following we assume $n \geqslant 3$. Since

\begin{align}
f_n \biggl(\frac{\pi}{2n-1}\biggr) &= f_{n-2}\biggl(\frac{\pi}{2n-1}\biggr) + \tan \frac{\pi(n-1)}{2n-1} + \tan \frac{\pi n}{2n-1}\\
&= f_{n-2}\biggl(\frac{\pi}{2n-1}\biggr) + \tan \biggl(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4n-2}\biggr) + \tan \biggl(\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4n-2}\biggr)\\
&= f_{n-2}\biggl(\frac{\pi}{2n-1}\biggr)\\
&> 0,
\end{align}

it follows that $x_n \in \bigl(\frac{\pi}{2n}, \frac{\pi}{2n-1}\bigr)$. Write $x_n = \frac{1}{n}\bigl(\frac{\pi}{2} + \delta_n\bigr)$. Then $0 < \delta_n < \frac{\pi}{4n-2}$, in particular $\delta_n < \frac{3}{5} x_n$.

We use $\tan \bigl(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\bigr) = \cot x$, and

$$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{2} < \cot x < \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{3}\tag{1}$$

for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ in our calculations. First we have

$$-\tan (n x_n) = -\tan \biggl(\frac{\pi}{2} + \delta_n\biggr) = \cot \delta_n = \frac{1}{\delta_n} + O(\delta_n).\tag{2}$$

To determine the asymptotic behaviour of $\delta_n$, we next note that (since $f_n(x_n) = 0$)

\begin{align}
-\tan (nx_n) &= \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} \tan (k x_n)\\
&= \sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} \tan \bigl((n-m)x_n\bigr)\\
&= \sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} \tan \biggl(\frac{\pi}{2} - (mx_n - \delta_n)\biggr)\\
&= \sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} \cot (mx_n - \delta_n).
\end{align}

The inequalities $(1)$ now yield

$$\sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m x_n - \delta_n} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} (m x_n - \delta_n) < -\tan (n x_n) < \sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m x_n - \delta_n} - \frac{1}{3} \sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} (m x_n - \delta_n).\tag{3}$$

We find

$$\sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} (m x_n - \delta_n) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x_n - (n-1)\delta_n = (n-1)\frac{\pi - 2\delta_n}{4}$$

and

\begin{align}
\sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m x_n -\delta_n} &= \sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m x_n} + \frac{\delta_n}{x_n^2} \sum_{m = 1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m\bigl(m - \frac{\delta_n}{x_n}\bigr)}\\
&= \frac{\log n + \gamma + O(n^{-1})}{x_n} + O(\delta_n x_n^{-2}).
\end{align}

With $x_n^{-1} \sim \frac{2}{\pi} n$ it follows that

$$\frac{1}{\delta_n} \sim - \tan (n x_n) = \frac{2}{\pi}n \log n + O(n),$$

or

$$\delta_n = \frac{\pi}{2n\log n}\bigl( 1 + O\bigl((\log n)^{-1}\bigr)\bigr).\tag{4}$$

With some tedious work, we can get some bounds on the $O\bigl((\log n)^{-1}\bigr)$ term in $(4)$, but since $\frac{\pi}{12} < \frac{2\gamma}{\pi} < \frac{\pi}{8}$, what we have isn't sufficient to even determine whether it is $\Theta\bigl((\log n)^{-1}\bigr)$.

However, $(4)$ suffices to show that

$$\begin{split}x_n &= \frac{1}{n}\biggl(\frac{\pi}{2} + \delta_n\biggr) = \frac{\pi}{2n}\biggl(1 + \frac{1 + O\bigl((\log n)^{-1}\bigr)}{n\log n}\biggr)\\ &= \frac{\pi}{2n\bigl(1 - \frac{1 + O((\log n)^{-1})}{n\log n}\bigr)} = \frac{\pi}{2\bigl(n - (\log n)^{-1} + O((\log n)^{-2})\bigr)}.\end{split}\tag{5}$$

Concerning the difference between the empirical best-fit constants and the exact asymptotic values, recall [Legendre's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_constant). The logarithm is a very slowly varying function, to eliminate effects of constants from empirical estimates, one may need *very* large numbers. However, it may be that $250000$ is large enough, and the difference between the best-fit and the exact values is caused by the larger deviation from the asymptotic behaviour for the smaller $n$. Try a best-fit for e.g. $200000 \leqslant n \leqslant 250000$ to see what that gives.

Comment: i was working with an very similar approach, but what has bugged me (and was  avoiding me from posting an answer) was the justification why we can replace $\cot(x)\sim 1/x $ for any $m$. can you comment on this? Very nice answer btw (+1)

Comment: It turns out that we can do that because of $(1)$. The error made by that replacement is $\Theta(x)$, and it turns out that this is small enough to not influence the asymptotic behaviour (the sum of these errors is $\Theta(n)$, and the sum of the $\frac{1}{x}$ terms is $\Theta(n\log n)$). I wasn't sure that would work before I did the calculations either.

Comment: this makes sense, thank you very much!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer ! Thank you so much. I shall redo the fit tomorrow morning and let you know. Cheers.

Comment: @DanielFischer. Done and impressive ! Have a look to my update. Thanks again.

Comment: I do not know if you looked at the update. What is really impressive to me is how "different" are $\frac{\pi }{2 \left(n-\frac{1}{\log (n)}\right)}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)$. Just out of pure curiosity, do you think that this could be extended to the $k^{th}$ positive root ?

Comment: I just had time to take a short look yesterday, @ClaudeLeibovici. I'd be interested whether the estimates for $b$ and $c$ change noticeably if you increase the lower bound for the samples (you probably still have the $(n,x_n)$ data lying around, then making a fit with lower bounds $k\cdot 10^5$, $k=1,2,3,4$ shouldn't take much time). Extending it to the second positive root $x^{(2)}_n$ wouldn't be too hard, I think. Nor the $k^{th}$ positive root, as long as you look at the asymptotics for $n \to \infty$. It would be bad if you look at the $k^{th}$ root if $k$ is not much smaller than $n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just a long comment. When you deal with quantities that converge to $0$ you have to be careful with the sence of the approximation. Notice that if we take any two sequences $x_n,y_n$ such that 
$$ x_n,y_n \in [\frac{\pi}{2n},\frac{\pi}{2n - 1}]$$
then
$|x_n - y_n| \leq \frac{\pi}{2n - 2} - \frac{\pi}{2n} = \frac{2\pi}{(2n - 2)(2n)} = \Theta(\frac{1}{n^2})$
hence
$$\frac{|x_n - y_n|}{x_n} = \Theta(\frac1n),$$ 
so even the relative error goes to $0$. So it may seems that $\frac{\pi}{2n- 1}$ is a good approximation but in fact is as good as any other. So to define a good approximation we should require instead
$$\frac{|x_n - y_n|}{x_n} = o(\frac1n).$$ 
With this definition you can see at least numericaly that $\frac{\pi}{2n}$ is the right approximation as Cave jonhson pointed out.

Comment: I would totally agree if we could go to $o(\frac1{n^2})$ since $\frac \pi {2n}$ is the left asymptote.