# root finding for a tangent-like function

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have a tangent-like function, which means it increases monotonically, and at some value suddenly changes from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$. Is there any efficient numerical method to find all the roots of such tangent-like function in a given interval? What I can think of is just dividing the interval into several sub-intervals, and find roots in each of them. But it is inefficient and sometimes will miss some roots.

Comment: May we know what is the function ?

Comment: The analytical form of the function in unknown. Only know its discrete value on the mesh.

Comment: If this is the case, I agree with your last statements.

Comment: Even if one has to search the root at each sub-intervals, is there any good strategy for dividing these sub-intervals?

Comment: Sorry for the delay ! Fist of all, when you say $\infty$, do you mean a large values or NaN (not a number) ? Have a look to this problem of mine athttps://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961871/about-the-first-positive-root-of-sum-k-1n-tankx-0 There are $n$ roots but the distance between them becomes very small. So, just make the step size as small as you can afford it. May be you will miss some roots. Could it possible to have more details ?

Comment: In any manner, for this kind of problems with an undefined number of asymptotes, when you have bracketed the solution, I suggest you use a combinaison of bisection and Newton steps (even if the derivative has to be computed numerically). At least, this would speed up the root polishing process.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I am not sure how to do,  say, a robust secant method for this problem? OP only has the value of the function on a discrete mesh. I would interpolate the target function using a cubic polynomial and four nodes which bracket the root, and then use the root(s) of this polynomial as an approximation. It might be helpful to treat each computed approximation as a function of the grid spacing and then use Richardson's techniques to estimate the error.

Comment: @CarlChristian. I fully agree with your idea. There are many possible ways for this kind of problems. I guess that the key problem remains : how to bracket the root ? When this is done, everything becomes simple. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: the infinity means a very large number. Besides, the first order derivative of this unknown function can be exact calculated on the mesh.

Comment: @Carl Christian: Thank you for providing a good idea that using a polynomial to bracket the root and make a good initial guess.